# Sorting with Sorted function and lambda

Tags: python, api, sorting, lambda

Found this code snippet which is sorting a list of items by display_order:

```
conditions = sorted(conditions,
                    key=lambda x: (x.display_order, x.condition_guid != condition.condition_guid))
```

Where conditions is a list:

```
conditions: [
        Conditions 49, 015c0dec-26b8-4343-93fc-27d36548ae0a, 
        Conditions 48, 0bab9d83-b730-4c23-986b-e3ff5b0240a2, 
        Conditions 50, 7cd47bd1-0073-45a4-9793-3ed83f93b213, 
        Conditions 51, ce684f3c-954e-43af-8289-77c4cd835131, 
        Conditions 52, 8fce7db6-6813-4a46-a56c-731b7eb2d4bf]
```

Sorted function follows this syntax:

```
sorted(iterable, key=None, reverse=False)
```

where iterable = conditions.

Wondering the meaning of the parenthesis and comma in the lambda function:

```
(x.display_order, x.condition_guid != condition.condition_guid)
```

Comment: But don't you wonder why a lambda is used as the key parameter?

Comment: Can you clarify what your *conditions* list really looks like. The code, as presented, isn't runnable

Comment: `x` is a tuple,

Answer (score 0):

`key` in `sorted` does not have to be a single value, it can be a set to provide secondary sorting characteristics.

Comment: When the key is composed of several values, is each value indicating the order of the sort? In this example, the display_order has higher precedence over the condition_guid?

Comment: @JohnBarton exactly. It also filteres if you use a condition, falsey values first, truthy values second.